# Error with "Drop" when starting up Mathematica

Tags: manipulate, warning-messages, kernel-startup

This is for v11.2. Sometimes when I open up and then evaluate a notebook, the following messages appear:

```
Drop::drop: Cannot drop positions 1 through 1 in Manipulate`Dump`duration.
Drop::drop: Cannot drop positions 1 through 1 in Removed[$$Failure].
Drop::drop: Cannot drop positions 1 through 1 in Removed[$$Failure].
General::stop: Further output of Drop::drop will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

Mathematica then just hangs. Every time this happens I have to restart Mathematica or restart the kernel several times. Also, I don't understand how I can be getting errors associated with `Drop` and `Manipulate` when I those functions aren't used in the notebooks I'm opening. Uninstalling and reinstalling hasn't fixed this.

Comment: Have you changed the default style file?

Comment: Possibly... but I thought I reset it. Just to make sure, how would I go about resetting it to default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am seeing the same error messages now that I have installed v11.2

When the error occurs, check in Task Manager if there are multiple instances of the Kernel running. Kill all of them from task manager. Then start a new kernel from the Evaluation menu. Then evaluate your notebook. This usually works.

I have no idea why I occasionally get two or more instances of the kernel. Maybe it has something to do with loading .Net support

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
ReinstallNET["Force32Bit" -> True];
```

I am finding v11.2 prone to becoming unresponsive very easily.

Comment: A contributing factor may also be multiple definitions in different contexts for the same named item. e.g. definition in a Package and in Global space.

Comment: I reinstalled 11.2 and it was working alright until today. Concerning multiple kernels: usually there's one kernel doing nothing and the other using up CPU. I have no issues killing the former, but the latter is very hard to get rid of. I think I'll just downgrade to v11.0 or earlier for now...